# Change month and day only in BigQuery

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, sql-update

Is there an equivalent to `DATEFROMPARTS`in BigQuery? I'm trying to change only the month and day in my timestamp, not the year.

Here's my table in DATETIME:

```
BirthYear 
2014-12-12T00:00:00
2015-01-07T00:00:00
```

I want to change **only** the month and day but keep the year. For example change the bottom row to: `2015-04-01T00:00:00`

The following query works in MS SQL and I'm trying to rewrite it in BigQuery:

```
UPDATE `table` SET BirthYear = DATEFROMPARTS(BirthYear, 04, 01) WHERE BirthYear IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery equivalent of `datefromparts(year(birthdate), 4, 1)` is

```
date(extract(year from BirthYear), 4, 1)
```

also, if you need it to "convert" back to datetime you might want to use as below

```
datetime(date(extract(year from BirthYear), 4, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

For the following SQL Server expression:

```
datefromparts(year(birthdate), 4, 1)
```

In BigQuery, you could do this with `datetime_trunc()`  and `datetime_add()`:

```
datetime_add(datetime_trunc(birthdate, year), interval 4 month)
```

This gives you a `datetime` value. You can use `date_trunc()` and `date_add()` if you want to handle `date`s instead.